# Visual Studio Dev Server Vs Local IIS Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

This is a 2 part question

Q1. In codebehind, I have the following to get the Active Directory ID.

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

When using VS Dev Server, it gives the correct AD ID. But when using Local IIS Server, it returns an empty string. Why? How can I get the AD ID using Local IIS Web server?

Q2. In codebehind, I have an executable (e.g. abc.exe) which I am executing using System Diagnostic Process. This exe file is stored in project's bin folder.

When using Local IIS Web server, it executes fine. However when using VS Dev Server, it goes into catch complaining it cant find the exe file. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: For the first one, try disabling anonymous authentication in local IIS - just use Windows Authentication.   Not sure on the second one.

Comment: @blueprranha,  for your second question, can you post the exception detail please ?